# How do I fix this code to create an array of strings?

Tags: c, arrays

I want to create an array of strings. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
  char str1[] = {'f','i'};
  char str2[] = {'s','e'};
  char str3[] = {'t','h'};
  char arry_of_string[] = {str1,str2,str3};
  printf("%s\n",arry_of_string[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

This is the line that doesn't work:

```
char arry_of_string[] = {str1,str2,str3};
```

How do I correct it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you would like to create an array of *strings*, you are missing an asterisk, and terminating zeros:

```
char str1[] = {'f','i','\0'};
char str2[] = {'s','e','\0'};
char str3[] = {'t','h','\0'};
char *arry_of_string[] = {str1,str2,str3};
```

There is an easier way of doing the individual strings, too:

```
char str1[] = "fi";
char str2[] = "se";
char str3[] = "th";
char *arry_of_string[] = {str1,str2,str3};
```

When you use the `char x[] = "..."` construct, the content of your string literal (which includes a terminating zero) is copied into memory that you are allowed to write, producing the same effect as `char x[] = {'.', '.', ... '\0'}` construct.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the \0 terminate fault in my code, and easier way. there is a close relationship between array and pointer

Comment: @yozloy, there _is_ a close relationship between array and pointers, but make sure you don't make the common mistake of thinking they are the same.

Answer (score 2):

you can use it like this:(notice that if you want to print an array of char, u must have it termitated by '\0')

```
int main()
{
    char str1[] = {'f','i','\0'};
    char str2[] = {'s','e','\0'};
    char str3[] = {'t','h','\0'};
    char* arry_of_string[] = {str1,str2,str3};

    for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n",arry_of_string[i]);

    }
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for a [pointer](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/) here rather than a direct array.

```
char *arry_of_string[] = {str1,str2,str3};
```

An array is a collection of values, a pointer is a list of addresses containing values, so a char pointer is a pointer to the address of the arrays containing your strings (character arrays). *and breathe*

Comment: cplusplus dot com is a terrible website. Please try to refer to other sources.

Comment: @Shahbaz any better website for reference?

Comment: Great explanation, But I need time to digest it

Comment: @yozloy, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_%28computer_programming%29)? Most of google search results with "C pointer", such as [this](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/106/).

Answer (score 1):

you could just use:

```
const char *array_of_string[] = {"fi", "se", "th"};

int i;
for (i=0;i<3;i++) {
    printf("%s\n", array_of_string[i]);
}
```

if you want to be concise...

Comment: That should generate a warning unless you declare it as `const char *` rather than just `char *`.

Comment: This looks handy, but I think it involve more deeper topic like static array

Answer (score 0):

When you specify the string as

```
char* myString = "abcd";
```

It creates a pointer of type array and points to the base address or the 0th element of the character array. So myString points to a.
Using a char* is useful because c provides a good way of printing out the entire array using

```
printf("%s",myString);
```

Also pointer is useful to use when you dont know or dont want to specify the length of the char array.
Your question should be solved if you do this

```
  char *str1 = "fi";
  char *str2 = "se";
  char *str3 = "th";
  char* arry_of_string[] = {str1,str2,str3};
  int i;

  for (i=0;i<3;i++)
  {
    printf("%s\n",arry_of_string[i]);
  }
  return 0;
```

Feel free to mark the question answered if you are satisfied.